# How to find PID of test runner

Tags: adb, apk, automation

I have my app and my tests saved as following:

```
App package name: com.my.app
Test runner: com.my.app.test
```

When I run the app by itself, I can use adb to see the pid of my app: `adb shell ps | grep com.my.app`

```
u0_a839      14710  1044 41927360 714352 0                  0 S com.my.app
```

When I run my app with automation, I tried calling the same adb command while the tests were running: `adb shell ps | grep com.my.app.test`
But nothing shows up.

Comment: I would try to use `frida-ps` from Python frida-tools. You don't need a rooted device or install anything on device for `frida-ps`. Just execute `frida-ps -Ua` and it will list you all running apps by packageName and their pid.